# Convert FeatureLike type into GeoJSON feature?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

How to convert Feature type into GeoJSON feature?

I have tried this:

```
var feature: FeatureLike;
var writer = new GeoJSON();
const res = writer.writeFeatureObject(feature);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: The GeoJSON `writeFeatureObject` method only takes a Feature.  If you had a RenderFeature you would need to convert it to a Feature `const res = writer.writeFeatureObject(feature instanceof RenderFeature ? toFeature(feature) : feature);` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_render_Feature.html#.toFeature

Comment: Thank you lot! Post it as answer, I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GeoJSON `writeFeatureObject` method only takes a Feature.  If you had a RenderFeature you would need to convert it to a Feature

```
const res = writer.writeFeatureObject(feature instanceof RenderFeature ? toFeature(feature) : feature);
```

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_render_Feature.html#.toFeature